# Changing VolumeID inside wine

Tags: wine

How can I change disk volume id in wine?

There is **vol** command in windows which shows volume id and **[VolumeID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897436.aspx)** (from Sysinternals) which can change VolumeID in windows but not in wine.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Adam: First thing that comes to mind - some braindead registration scheme that relies on the volume ID as part of its key validation algorithm (IMHO people who do that should be forced to watch lolcat pictures for 18 hours a day, but that's just me - more lenient people would probably just call for mild electrocution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running winecfg allows you to edit the drive serial/label (among many other things) from a GUI. If you just want to manipulate it from the filesystem, create the following files as appropriate:

```
.wine/drive_c/.windows-label:MYDRIVE
.wine/drive_c/.windows-serial:12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a pain in the butt to do this but if you have a copy of windows you could copy explorer.exe (and any of the files that it needs to run) to wine. Then just change the VolumeID like normal. An easier way might be to find the vol command on your windows installation (they usually have .com extensions) and copy it to wine so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
cd .wine
ln -s drive_c myvolid
cd dosdevices
ln -sf "c:" ../myvolid
```